# Does Windows 7 allow auto-login with a stored password, like TweakUI did?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, login, password-management

The TweakUI powertoy for Windows XP had an option to auto-login. It stored your password and did the login for you. This was useful, since you kept password protection, but had login programs loaded when you first booted.

When you switched users or hibernated, it would still ask for a password, which is the desired behavior.

Is there a way of doing this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yep. Run `control userpasswords2` from the command line. Uncheck the box for "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer". When you click "Apply", you'll be asked for the username/password combo you want to use to login. This user will then get logged in automatically.

[image: User account auto login]

[image: select user]

Comment: I found this as well: http://torch.freeweb7.com/autologon.html -- it auto logon (to load programs, etc) and lock immediately. exactly what i needed :)

Comment: If you want to have it lock automatically, just add a shortcut to `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` to your Startup folder. No need to install third party programs.

Comment: An (unstated) important step is that by disabling`Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer`, you are allowed to select the user which you want to be the default account, once you have selected the user and you enable `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer` and hit apply the prompt is displayed.  There are numerous other questions with slightly incomplete answers, this answer does work for ALL accounts, even those without a password.

Answer (score 3):

TweakUI is just a GUI interface for registry keys, which can also be accessed using [**Systinternals Autologon**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905).

Answer (score 3):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]

"AutoAdminLogon"="1"

"DefaultUserName"="USER@AD-DOMAIN"

"DefaultPassword"="PASSWORD"

"ForceAutoLogon"="0"
```

Comment: what will this do?