# Windows 7 auto-login script

Tags: windows-7, script, auto-login

I'm running Windows 7, and I want it to display a password prompt when I lock my screen, as is normal. However, I want to have a script/service that somehow logs me in when it's invoked via an external hardware device (for example, a listener detects an RFID card touch and invokes the script, or an iPhone sends a command to a listener server and it invokes the script). A script that would store my username/password in plaintext is okay.

(I don't need this functionality at startup or the very first time I login, I only need it after I've already logged in and I lock my screen.)

Is it possible to create such a script? If so, could you point me to an existing solution or a starting point for building one myself?

I do understand the security implications of what I'm asking for, but I still want answers to my question as presented.

Comment: Let me clarify: Start up computer, automatically get logged in, but retain the ability to lock the workstation?

Comment: The usual way of [doing auto-login in Win7](http://superuser.com/questions/243681/does-windows-7-allow-auto-login-with-a-stored-password-like-tweakui-did/243684#243684) doesn't allow you to lock the station?

Comment: What sort of trigger would you be using to invoke the process?

Comment: All: I've updated my question to be more specific. Hope it helps.

Comment: [BtProx](http://btprox.sourceforge.net/) locks your workstation when a Bluetooth device leaves proximity, but it is unclear whether it unlocks when the device comes back into proximity.

Answer (score 1):

try Rohos Logon Key http://www.rohos.com/products/rohos-logon-key/ I use it with a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually wondered about building RFID-card actuated login systems. It wouldn't be that different from a fingerprint login system.

In searching I have not found a script that does this, but there are several companies that offer solutions (hardware and software) to do this. One appears to have their drivers and app available for download. I'm not sure if you can crack it open enough to leverage their knowledge, but it's at least a start, I think.

http://www.id.ee/?id=28902&&langchange=1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'd be rather sad if this was the closest thing that exists that solves this problem. I've come across mentions about creating Windows credential providers that might solve this problem, but there is very little info out there about them and what exactly it is they do. Have you looked at those?

Comment: Most of the solutions seem to rely on digital certificates to provide the actual authentication. I'd imagine the digital certificate process is documented as part of the Windows Source Code (I'm pulling a blank on the real name, the big windows developer kit thing-a-ma-bob) and may be extensible through that system if you're willing to give that method a crack.