# Windows 8 auto login

Tags: windows-8, passwords, auto-login

On Windows 8 I don't have the option on a PC I am dealing with to auto login.

In netplwiz I don't have the checkbox, as screenshotted:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please fix your screenshot

Answer (score 5):

Windows 8 is fairly smart, if you do not have the option - then you are most likely on a `domain` (i.e. a work computer that has policies set for computers on the domain by a central authority trying to encourage security).

Otherwise you are in the right spot, and since the image does not show the necessary checkbox - my bet is you are on a `domain`.

Take a look at [Microsoft's page on that](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/turn-on-automatic-logon).

**An untested workaround**

I am not about to test this on my work domain nor would I suggest this, but for the intel piece, do the following as an admin.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `regedit`
2. Navigate (on the left) to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winlogon`  Set the value for `AutoAdminLogon = 1` (1 = auto, 0 = off)
3. Create a string value called `DefaultPassword`, in the value field enter your password.
4. Look for/create a value for `DefaultUserName` (type: REG_SZ), make that the user you want logged in by default.
5. If you are on a `domain`, you may need to add a string for `DefaultDomainName` with the value of the domain you are on.

Again, this is untested.  I take no responsibility for you breaking your computer messing around in the registry or angering an IT manager for having an auto-logon setup.

I would discourage it since you really shouldn't need to logout and in that often and it isn't too hard to type out a password for those occasions.  That being said, if you try it and it does/doesn't work - please report back for future peoples.

Comment: Well in this case the domain is my own domain used for the microsoft login nonsense. Why should this prevent it?

Comment: @MarcusHughes - Updated.  Looks like STTR also has the fast way of adding keys for you.

Comment: No luck, neither (same things) worked

Comment: @MarcusHughes - _This is the right answer to your question_.  You asked why the check-box was missing, and the reason is because you've joined a domain.  If your question is actually _"How do I enable auto-logon when the box is missing"_, then that's a different question, one which may have answers here (amongst other places): [Does Windows 7 allow auto-login with a stored password, like TweakUI did?](http://superuser.com/questions/243681/does-windows-7-allow-auto-login-with-a-stored-password-like-tweakui-did)

Comment: It's not the correct answer as I am certain I am not on a domain

Comment: @MarcusHughes - You said "the domain is my own domain", not sure why you expect people to not think you are - on a place like this, we are just nerdy enough to have home domains. What version of W8 are you on?

Comment: I am on W8 Pro. And as for "domain", I have my microsoft account on my own domain name ... I just think the two got confused, my login is hello@mydomain.tld

Answer (score 3):

command line:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d  %USERNAME%
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d <Your password>
```

Domain, if need:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d %USERDNSDOMAIN%
```

Comment: This did not have any effect

Comment: @MarcusHughes `REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserSwitch" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

Answer (score 3):

I always use [AutoLogon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx) from Sysinternals.

With this way that data are encrypted.

Comment: I also tried this, no luck

Comment: You must run it with admin rights: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token

Comment: No, this didn't work. I just retested

Comment: I use this tool for years and it works. Do you use a local or MS account?

Comment: It was a Microsoft account, I tried converting it yesterday to see if it would work but still no luck. I understand it may work for you but it doesn't here and that's why I am asking for assistance?...

Comment: Try it again without a running AV tool. If this also doesn't help I have no other idea.