# Windows 10 Disable Welcome Screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, embedded, iot

Is there a way to disable the welcome screen in Windows 10?

I already found an option to disable the lockscreen and the boot screen, but the welcome screen with the username and account image still pops up.

I want to do this because we are using Windows 10 IoT on an industrial pc. We do not want the end-user to see anything Windows related.

We also changed the shell launcher and have a keyboard filter.

Comment: Have you tried configuring a default user?  This allows you to configure the user to automatically log into the device.

Comment: Are you looking for [auto-login](https://superuser.com/questions/243681/does-windows-7-allow-auto-login-with-a-stored-password-like-tweakui-did) ?

Comment: No auto-login is already enabled. But I dont want the user to see the welcome loading page. As I sad our goal is to disable everything that looks like Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to suppress the screen entirely, but you can at least change
the background picture that is displayed:

- Enter PC Settings > Personalization > Lock screen
- Under Background, click the drop-box to replace "Windows spotlight" with "Picture"
- Click Browse and choose your background image.

For changing the logo that is displayed during the boot, there are two cases:

- UEFI BIOS : Use [HackBGRT](https://www.intowindows.com/hackbgrt-windows-10-uefi-boot-logo-changer/)
  as explained
  [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-windows-boot-logo-using-hackbgrt).
- Legacy BIOS : See [this video](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-windows-10-boot-screen).

Comment: We already did that. But it still looks too much like Windows 10 for our use.

Comment: Added some more customizations.

Comment: As I sad. We already customized everything we were able too. There is no Windows boot logo or anything. The background while loggin in is also changed. The last thing we want to change is this screen: https://images.tenorshare.com/topics/fix-windows/windows10-stuck-on-welcome-screen.jpg

Comment: The above are all the known customizations. For doing more, you will need to hack Windows, most likely the involved DLLs, which might not work if they are digitally signed by Microsoft. But unfortunately this isn't suitable content for this site.